# "Create IP Address" not found during creation of load balancer for static website

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-load-balancer

I follow the instruction from https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website to setup static website, but in the dropdown menu on "IP address" field, there is no "Create IP address" field as you can see in the screenshot, how should I address that?

Please see the screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: Do you have **Standard** or **Premium** network service tier enabled? https://cloud.google.com/network-tiers

Answer (score 1):

You can proceed on selecting the Ephemeral as the IP Address type. It will then assign an available IP Address from the IP Address pool from its region.

As Ephemeral IP is susceptible to change, you can then later promote it as a [Static IP Address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) from the Navigation Menu > VPC Network > IP Addresses.